# Appointment Manager/Scheduler module and component for Joomla 1.5

Tags: module, joomla, components

I want to setup a scheduler so the Practitioner can set certain hours that they are available for appointments, then the user/client can go to the site and schedule a session. This would be for like a massage business. I do not want the practitioner to have to go in all the time and add dates. They should be able to just set it. Nothing quite looks like this in the extensions site. For example:

I am available Tuesdays, Wednesdays 2pm-6pm and Saturday 10am-3pm.

Session types:
30min
60min
90 min
120 min

Maybe this would then email the practitioner and the User? Taking payments would be even better!

Does anything like this for 1.5 exist? Anyone want to be the next extension star and write it?

Regards,
Atul

Answer (score 0):

You should try EventList 1.1
http://www.schlu.net/eventlist-overview.html

Comment: thanks for the reply. I implemented a custom calendar module for joomla as i was not able to get the module which exactly matches my requirement.